# SAVING & RETRIEVING FROM FIRESTORE

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to send data from two forms to firebase's firestore but only one function for sending is to be working there's an error that is blocking the second function to be run. The error displaying in the console is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

This is my script for the first form

```
function post(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    db.collection('Posts').add({
        Author_Names: postform.authornames.value,
        Description: postform.description.value,
        Info: postform.info.value,
        Citation: postform.citation.value,
       // Cover_Image: postform.cover.value,
    })
    postform.reset();
}
document.getElementById('postblog').addEventListener('click', post);/*This is where the error is displayed*/

// create element & retrieve post
function renderpost(doc){
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let Author_Names = document.createElement('h2');
    let Description = document.createElement('h5');
    let Info = document.createElement('p');
    let Citation = document.createElement('h5');
    let Delete = document.createElement('button');
    Delete.setAttribute("class", "btn");
    let update = document.createElement('button');
    update.setAttribute("class", "btn");
    
    li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    Author_Names.textContent = doc.data().Author_Names;
    Description.textContent = doc.data().Description;
    Info.textContent = doc.data().Info;
    Citation.textContent = doc.data().Citation;
    Delete.textContent = 'Delete';
    update.textContent = 'Update';

    li.appendChild(Author_Names);
    li.appendChild(Description);
    li.appendChild(Info);
    li.appendChild(Citation);
    li.appendChild(Delete);
    li.appendChild(update);

    postlist.appendChild(li);
```

And this my script for the second form

```
const contactform = document.querySelector("#contactform");
const messagelist = document.querySelector("#messagelist");
const messageform = document.querySelector('message-form');

//Messages

//Saving new messages to firestore
function send(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    db.collection('Messages').add({
        Names: contactform.names.value,
        email: contactform.email.value,
        Message: contactform.message.value,
        Comments: contactform.comments.value,
    });
    contactform.reset();
}
document.getElementById('messagebtn').addEventListener('click', send);

// create element & render message
function rendermessages(doc){
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let Names = document.createElement('h2');
    let email = document.createElement('h5');
    let Message = document.createElement('p');
    let Comments = document.createElement('h5');
    let Delete = document.createElement('button');
    let update = document.createElement('button');

    li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    Names.textContent = doc.data().Names;
    email.textContent = doc.data().email;
    Message.textContent = doc.data().Message;
    Comments.textContent = doc.data().Comments;
    Delete.textContent = 'Delete';
    update.textContent = 'Update';

    li.appendChild(Names);
    li.appendChild(email);
    li.appendChild(Message);
    li.appendChild(Comments);
    li.appendChild(Delete);
    li.appendChild(update);

    messagelist.appendChild(li);
```

I tried using an anonymous function but it was of no use, I've also triple checked my html ids, classes and names and everything matches with the ones I used on the JS.

Comment: Means it can not find the element. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I separated the functions in different files and the bugs were gone. It seems like they conflict a lot when used in one file. Also, try using the click eventListener other than the submit.

Answer (score 0):

Error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` is due to be calling addEventListener on a not defined object.

Verify that `document.getElementById('messagebtn')` is well defined and that the button you are willing to listen on this function has the same ID as in the code.

Usually this kind of errors are due to a typo on either side.

Comment: I don't think that might be the issue on this one, I tried checking that by commenting out one function then the other one worked perfectly. Unless the functions are conflicting somehow.

Comment: If the functions are working separately but when both are declared at the same time one is broken usually is an ids issue or a scope issue. doublecheck how you are acessing the buttons on the code and that the scope is the correct one